# Loop through each row from a user input range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been researching on this for quite awhile but none of my code work so far, so I wish someone can help. I created a userform that has 2 input boxes and a command button. I want the command button to highlight each row one at a time and then print out a copy with each higlighted row. For example, the user input "A5:J5" as the starting row from textbox1 then "A30:J30" as the ending row from textbox2. I want the command button to automatically highlight one row at a time and print out 1 copy for each row. 
Here is a part of the code. Not updated with looping and offset (which doesn't work anyways) as I don't have the copy of my updated code at the moment. I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
Private Sub PrintingButton_Click()

Dim firstrow As String
Dim firstrange As Range

Dim lastrow As String
Dim lastrange As Range

'highlight the firstrow

firstrow = TextBox1.Value
Set firstrange = Range(firstrow)

lastrow = TextBox2.Value
Set lastrange = Range(lastrow)

firstrange.Select
With Selection.Interior
.Color = 65535
'insert printing code here:    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Try to record a macro performing that task, and afterwards look at the code. For example in my case it would be something like `Application.ActivePrinter = "hp photosmart 7200 series en Ne01:"
    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:= _
        "hp photosmart 7200 series en Ne01:", Collate:=True`

Comment: I did that. The printing code works just fine. I just need to know how to loop using loop range name to print each row. Recording the macro will not help because the rows are not constant that's why i need to create a userform with textboxes for input.

Comment: I'm not sure, since I'm not an expert, but I think that, since you are selecting a range (`firstrange.Select`), then `Selection.PrintOut` should work. Your code says `SelectedSheets.PrintOut`. Try to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following. Seems to work for me.

```
Private Sub PrintingButton_Click()
    Dim firstrow As String
    Dim lastrow As String
    Dim rMyRange As Range


    firstrow = TextBox1.Value 'Input value like "A5" (just the upper letf cell of desired range, not range as in you example)
    lastrow = TextBox2.Value 'Input value like "B10" (just the bottom right cell of desired range, not range)

    'data is supposed to be located in sheet "MyData"
    Set rMyRange = Worksheets("MyData").Range(firstrow, lastrow)

        For Each MyRow In rMyRange.Rows
        MyRow.Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Color = 65535
            'Your printer settings here
            Application.ActivePrinter = "hp photosmart 7200 series (Copiar 1) en Ne01:"
        ActiveWindow.Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:= _
            "hp photosmart 7200 series (Copiar 1) en Ne01:", Collate:=True

            End With
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh i see. I thought I need to input the entire range. That's why i was having a hard time. I also did not include the sheet name on my code. This works great! I just added a few code like MyRow.Interior.Color = xlNone so it will highlight one row per print. Thank you so much!